# Looking an efficient alternative for [myTableView reloadData] in objective c

Tags: objective-c, uitableview

I have a refresh button to get current data and reload the tableView. I'm using this method to do this:

```
[self getCurrentData];
[self changeArrayObjectsWithNewDatas];
[self.myTableView reloadData];
```

But after a while, the application is slowing down. That's why I'm looking an efficient alternative for [myTableView reloadData]

Comment: And `reloadData` is the culprit?

Comment: Yes, after several inspections, I'm sure of it.

Comment: Actually, I've tested it. I've commented out the line [self.myTableView reloadData], and the application wasn't slowing down.

Comment: You should find exactly what's slowing down by using Instruments, and find faster alternatives to that. `reloadData` shouldn't be too slow on its own, but slow table vie delegate / data source code can make it slow.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`reloadData` isn't slow.   Your application's workload in response to `reloadData` is slow.

You need to profile your app using Instruments, determine what is slow, and fix it to either not be slow or to be done at a different spot.

If your app is slowing down over time, it is quite likely because you are accreting state on each data load.  That is, you might likely be keeping the previous result set around instead of releasing it.

You'll have to show more code before anyone can answer this more directly.  In particular, what do the implementations of the UITableViewDataSource methods look like?

Comment: Yeah, I've looked at it, the observer is the problem. Thank you so much, and I guess I have to ask another question :))

Answer (score 1):

The problem might be that you are reloading your data in the main thread, only the UI should be handled in the main thread.

Try this:

```
 - (void)fetchCurrentDataWithCompletion:(void (^)())completion
 {
     dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND, 0), ^{
         // Handle your loading
         [self changeArrayObjectsWithNewDatas];
         if (completion) {
             completion();
         } 
     }
 }
```

Then:

```
[self fetchCurrentDataWithCompletion:^{
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        [self.myTableView reloadData]; 
    });
}];
```

Answer (score 0):

what you can do is change only those values in the array that are providing the data for the cells already visible on the screen.. [visibleCells](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UITableView/visibleCells)  returns an array of the currently visible cells on the screen. as soon as you change the values, you can manually update the data displayed on those cells (ie without using [myTableView reloadData] data), just make sure you do that on the main thread.

You can then change the rest of the values in the array in separate (ie non main) thread..

to be safe you can change the values of the visible cells +- some cells just in case the user scrolls a lot..